# jquery mobile, google map body 100% higher

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQUERY MOBILE</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#map-canvas {
height: 100%;
margin: 0%;
padding: 5%
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // initialize
function initialize() {
    // mylatlng
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: myLatlng
};
    // set map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
// set marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
title: 'Hello World!'
});
marker.setMap(map);
}
    // initialize
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>GOOGLE MAPS V3</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<h1>#GOOGLE MAPS V3</h1>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

![enter image description here][2]

I want to do is that the body of the page that will contain the map can visualize 100% both high and wide, but without the head and foot desaparescan, please help with this problem

image is shown as figure want the map, but can not find how to square the canvas map, whenever I add the size 100% higher and 100% width several times the map canvas not included

Comment: Was this translated?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly you're trying to stretch your map 100% between your header and fixed footer.

If you look at the [jquery mobile example with google maps](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/map-geolocation/#&ui-state=dialog) they have their page container and map canvas set to 100% height with a header.  Here is their html...

```
<div data-role="page" id="map-page" data-url="map-page">
   <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" id="head">
      <h1>Maps</h1>
   </div>
   <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas">
    <!-- map loads here... -->
   </div>
</div>
```

and css...

```
<style>
   #map-page, #map-canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; }
</style>
```

This works as far as stretching the map but it adds (in their example) an extra 44 pixels due to the header that they don't account for.  I added a small script to fix this in a project I did a while back, this required setting the map to a global variable and calling a resize procedure once the page was loaded (I loaded map in page init).

```
function resize_map() {
    $('#map-canvas').height($('#map-canvas').height() - $('#head').height());
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}
```

There's also in the default style your using a 1px border that you would need to take care of.

Now if you want to add your fixed footer, you would also need to subtract the footer's height from map-canvas when setting the height.  There is also padding added to the page.

### Below is the code for what I think you were trying to accomplish...

```
<style type="text/css">
    #map-page, #map-canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0;}
    #map-page{padding-bottom:0px !important;}
    .ui-header, .ui-footer {border-width: 0px 0;}
</style>
```

Your styles, setting the page and map canvas to 100% height, removing the bottom padding added by the fixed footer, and getting rid of the border of the default styles you linked...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
        
    function resize_map() {
        $('#map-canvas').height($(window).height() - $('#head').height() - $('#foot').height());
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    }
    
    $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#map-page", function() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
           resize_map();
        });
    });
    
    $(document).on('pagecontainershow', function(){
        var pageid = $("body").pagecontainer("getActivePage").prop("id");
        
        if(pageid === "map-page"){
            resize_map();
        }
    });
</script>
```

The script draws the map and on page show we call our resize, subtracting the header and footer height.

```
<div data-role="page" id="map-page" data-url="map-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" id="head">
    <h1>Maps</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas">
        <!-- map loads here... -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"  id="foot" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>Google Maps V3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your basic html markup.

Edit: Changed to window.height if this is a browser application.  You would want to trigger the resize function whenever the window is resized.  Again this is to set the map the exact height between your fixed footer and header.